# Query to fall back on different columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a person table

```
CREATE TABLE Person
(
PersonID INT
Name varchar(50),
HireDate datetime,
HireOrder int,
AltOrder int
)
```

Assume I have data like this

```
INSERT INTO Person VALUES(1, 'Rob', '06/02/1988', 0, 0)
INSERT INTO Person VALUES(2, 'Tom', '05/07/2016', 0, 0)
INSERT INTO Person VALUES(3, 'Phil', '01/04/2011', 1, 0)
INSERT INTO Person VALUES(4, 'Cris', '01/04/2011', 2, 0)
INSERT INTO Person VALUES(5, 'Jen', '01/04/2011', 3, 0)
INSERT INTO Person VALUES(6, 'Bill', '01/05/2011', 0, 0)
INSERT INTO Person VALUES(7, 'Ray', '01/23/2012', 0, 0)
```

I'm trying to simplify my requirement... providing the input of HireDate, HireOrder, and AltOrder, I need to be able to pick up the next person

For ex:, if I provide input, HireDate: 06/02/1988, HireOrder:0, AltOrder:0, the return value expected is "Tom" because he is the next person after the provided input.

For ex:, if I provide input, HireDate: 05/07/2016, HireOrder:0, AltOrder:0, the return value expected is "Phil" because he is the next person after the provided input. Though Phil and Cris have same dates, their HireOrder takes precedence in this case. If they also have same HireOrder, AltOrder would be coming in picture to determine next person

Another ex: if I provide input, HireDate: 01/04/2011, HireOrder:1, AltOrder:0, the return value expected is "Cris" because she is the next person after the provided input. Here hireorder determines.

If I provide, HireDate: 01/23/2012, HireOrder:0, AltOrder:0, as there is no person after this, I should be able to pick the first person on the list - in this case Rob.

I can write some business logic in front-end, but I thought it would be good, if I can move this to a stored procedure which can return me the PersonID for optimal performance.

I have tried writing various conditions but couldn't achieve a query that meets all my requirements here. Any pointers in the right direction would be helpful for me. Thanks

Note: I'm even fine if my last condition is not met (returning the first person in the list, in case no one is available after the provided input).

Comment: Having PersonID not being the primary key of the Person table is cnofusing. All your IDs are 1, is this what you meant? You seem to be imagining the list has an inherent order. Tables do not have an inherent order in SQL. If you need an order you need to keep a column that specifies that order.

Comment: my copy/paste mistake; changed PersonIDs; they are unique

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a method with a rather complicated `where` clause:

```
select top 1 p.*
from person p
where (p.hiredate > @hiredate) or
      (p.hiredate = @hiredate and p.hireorder > @hireorder) or
      (p.hiredate = @hiredate and p.hireorder = @hireorder and p.altorder > @altorder)
order by hiredate, hireorder, altorder;
```

Comment: this works but not sure, if it is efficient in terms of execution time

Comment: parenthesis needs to be added for better clarity

Answer (score 1):

I agree that your PersonID is confusing, as it is the same value for everyone whereas you would think it should be a primary key. If you want to input a person's name into a stored procedure and return the next person in the list, this should work:

```
declare @SelectedPersonID int -- this would be a parameter in your stored procedure

;WITH CTE AS (
              select *
              ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY PersonID,HireOrder,AltOrder) AS RN
             from Person)
,CTE2 AS (select A.PersonID AS SelectedPersonID,B.*
          from CTE A left join CTE B on A.RN + 1 = B.RN)

select PersonID from CTE2 where SelectedPersonID = @SelectedPersonID
```